# How to preserved menu item states

Tags: asp.net, menu, asp.net-ajax, master-pages, devexpress

Work on Asp.net vs2008 C#.My project have one master page . My master page contain three parts,Like as bellow picture.Clicking on menu item,page show on part 3,I can do that. But I want clicking on menu ,just update the part 3 not 1 and 2.My present scenario is that ,click on menu item-3 post back whole page and menu control become reset.so after postback i can not get the selected menu item.I want after postback only my master page body update but not the menu control.

[image]

If have any query plz ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to organize the required layout with the use of the DevExpress ASPxSplitter (with set of SpitterPanes) and ASPxMenu / ASPxNavBars control:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/Splitter/ContentUrl.aspx

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/Splitter/FullscreenMode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are coding section 3 in your master page template where you should place a ContentPlaceHolder in section 3 and then create an ASPX page which has your master page specifed in the page directive.  You can find more information about how to use master pages and contentplaceholders [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).